# Charge distribution on uncharged conducting sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> A charge $q$ is brought to a distance $d$ from the center of an *uncharged, conducting* sphere of radius R. What is the charge per unit area of the sphere as a function of the polar angle $\theta$?

Can anyone offer an explanation on how to approach this problem?

I have already solved this problem once assuming that, instead of being uncharged, the sphere is grounded at a potential $\varphi =0$, but I am unable to see how the answer will be different for an "uncharged" sphere. What role does the sphere being "uncharged" play in the solution? I don't understand what implication being "uncharged" has on the physics involved in this problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I have specified that I do not understand what is implied by "uncharged" is this not suitable?

Comment: @Loonuh the answer is in the wording of this question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/202415/why-does-the-superposition-principle-work-in-method-of-images

Comment: BTW your *real* question is on-topic. The reason it was put on hold is that you copy-pasted the homework question, and you sort-of ask for its solution. I prefer the first edition of the OP, where you showed some effort by having solved the exercise for the grounded sphere.

Comment: I removed that solution because I assumed that it was falling under the "check my work" category. The mods are not especially helpful in their criticisms.

Comment: Bear in mind that moderators usually vote to close questions in around 10 seconds. If they got your point or not is a matter of discussion: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6467/careless-serial-voting

Comment: @Rol I still don't understand even after looking at your link. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: "...but I am unable to see how the answer will be different for an "uncharged" sphere". Just add (or subtract) a homogeneous charge until the total charge is 0.